# How to parse http response in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I sent post data via curl:

```
curl -X POST --form data='{"size": 1}' --form upload=@mini.jpg  http://127.0.0.1/index.html
```

I have access to this data in server in `NSData` container.
This data looks that:

```
--------------------------f4441c52f8cd3983
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"size": 1}
--------------------------f4441c52f8cd3983
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="mini.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

HÍ´Ÿb:m:RÈ©0Ý±±¯{Zî8ä‹uÉº\Ø¢§8Ò`<øû...
...
```

If I convert `NSData` to `NSString`:

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data.bytes length:data.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

than `NSString` is `(null`).

How to parse data and get Image bytes and json "size: 1"?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple), it's great!
Anyway,

```
NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",data];
```